# Ruby Checking if string contains substring

Tags: ruby

I have many log files, each contains a line like this one:

```
THIS LINE IS DIFFERENT CASE_WINDOWS_TEST_00 PASSED
```

I'm searching if line contains "_XXX_TEST_" string. I created a hash:

```
@@groups = {
    "_LINUX_TEST_" => "Linux_tests",
    "_WINDOWS_TEST_" => "Windows_tests"
}
```

To check if the line contains a substring (a key from @@groups) I implemented method get_group_name which returns a value from @@groups.

```
def get_group_name(searchLine)
    @@groups.keys.each do |i| 
        if searchLine.include? i
            return @@groups[i]
        end
    end
end
```

It works fine, returns proper values. I use this method in another method that iterates through log file.

```
def get_group_name_from_file(fileName)
    # fileName - filename or path to the file.txt
    file = File.open(fileName)
    while (line = file.gets)
        found = get_group_name(line)
        if found 
            return found
        end
    end
end
```

And here is the problem. Method get_group_name_from_file returns list of keys from @@groups hash instead of one string (a value from that hash).

Comment: can't reproduce

Answer (score 1):

I think, this problem could appear when your log file doesn't have lines that include any of your @@groups.keys, so for solve this problem, you can add this lines:

```
@@groups = {
    "_LINUX_TEST_" => "Linux_tests",
    "_WINDOWS_TEST_" => "Windows_tests"
  }

  def get_group_name(searchLine)
    @@groups[@@groups.keys.find { |key| searchLine.include? key }]
  end

  def get_group_name_from_file(fileName)
    # fileName - filename or path to the file.txt
    file = File.open(fileName)
    while (line = file.gets)
      found = get_group_name(line)
      return found if found
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your guess is correct, I think, but it's the other method that should be fixed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev try No:2 :)

Comment: Nope, get_group_name returns key, not value.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when it returns the output returned by *each* method if control doesn't reach upto:

```
return @group[i];
```

You can update method as:

```
def get_group_name(searchLine)
  @@groups.keys.each do |i| 
    if searchLine.include? i
      return @@groups[i]
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

One more option:

```
def get_group_name(searchLine)
  @groups.keys.detect do |i|
    if searchLine.include? i
      return @groups[i]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One more option:
    def get_group_name(searchLine)
     @groups.keys.detect do |i|
        if searchLine.include? i
          return @groups[i]
      end
  end
end

Comment: if we use detect, we don't need `if` or `return`

Comment: We need it because iteration is over the keys and not value. So it will return key but we want value.

Comment: Ah, right. In this case, this is a very bad usage of `detect`, I think. You only use it for its implicit `nil` return value (if nothing found). Misleading. I like the first one better. :)